# Should we migrate obvious programming questions to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, migration

This question

[How to print struct variables in console?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/18159/how-to-print-struct-variables-in-console)

is really just a programming question, even those the data that is being printed looks pretty devopsy.  But as we know, there are a zillion questions on stackoverflow and one like this is probably either a hard-to-find dupe or risks being completely ignored, even more than our little corner of the SE-verse.

That being said, do you want us to migrate the questions to SO or leave them here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think so. Even if it is a duplicate, I think questions like these are more tailored to that site.